# In Presto what data type results from NOW()

Tags: sql, presto

If I use NOW() in a query, what is the correct data type in a Presto Schema?

Answer (score 0):

From [Presto Date and Time Functions and Operators document](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html)

> now() → timestamp with time zone#
> This is an alias for current_timestamp.